# WebStorm remote debug using typescript... howto?

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I am currently debugging pure js Nodejs apps remotely over SSL using port mapping.

On the Linux server side I run `balance -df 8585 127.0.0.1:5858` to port map 8585 to 5858 and it works great with remote debugging and WebStorm.

so on server I run `node --debug-brk --nolazy ./someFile.js`
and put a breakpoint on Windows in WebStorm and all is great!

Now I would like to remote debug TypeScript files on server side instead of JS.

Is there any tutorial on that? Do I need to compiles to JS file every time on server side and where should I keep the sourceMap on Windows side where I put the breakpoints or on server side? How about the tsconfig?